# PostgreSQL order by special char

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

I have to sync two databases. The first one (source) run on Sybase and the second (dist) run on PostgreSQL. I make for each rows a comparaison to check if the row exist or not (comparaison of the pk). But, for a specific table, the pk is a varchar.

I make :

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY 1;
```

The table output look like this on Sybase :

```
# | row 1
.. | row 2
1 | row 3
...
```

and on PostgreSQL :

```
.. | row 1
# | row 2
1 | row 3
```

So, the rows have not the same order. I would like to obtain the same output in PostgreSQL that my Sybase db (SQL Anywhere).

Any idea ?

Comment: You need to match the collations between the two databases.  That requires some research into what the collations are in each database.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you need this query :

```
WITH x(a) AS (SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY 1)
SELECT *
FROM   x
ORDER  BY a COLLATE "C";
```